# TestNG parallel execution - issue with parallel classes

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am introducing parallel execution into my testNG suite. When I set 'parallel' to 'tests', two browsers open and the first classes from my two tests begin simultaneously - this is what I would expect. When I set it to 'classes', I would expect both classes from my first test to begin simultaneously, however only one browser opens, the first method from the first class executes, then a new browser opens with the first method from the second class, and so on. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my xml file:

```
<suite name="FullRegressionSuite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="reporting.CustomReporter"></listener>
</listeners>

  <test name="Test1">
  <parameter name ="Environment" value="Chrome_Hub"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="userManagement.LoginLogoutScript"/>
      <class name="carts.CartScript"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Test2">
  <parameter name ="Environment" value="Chrome_Hub"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="userManagement.AccountInformationScript"/>
      <class name="siteContent.ProductSearchAndFilterScript"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you are using static browser, if so, please avoid so to run test in parallel.

Please share where you initialising and launching browser.

Comment: I am launching it from a Base class using public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();   then driver.set(new ChromeDriver());    then in my scripts Base.driver.get().findElement etc. It was my understanding that using the threadlocal would allow me to use parallel processing, are you saying this is not true? If so, why does it work when I set parallel to 'tests'?